# Fill pandas fields with tuples as elements by slicing

Tags: pandas, tuples, slice

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but I did not find it here nor somewhere else:

I want to fill some of the fields of a column with tuples. Currently I would have to resort to:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4]})
df['b'] = ''
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(object)
mytuple = ('x','y')
for l in df[df.a % 2 == 0].index:
    df.set_value(l, 'b', mytuple)
```

with df being (which is what I want)

```
   a       b
0  1        
1  2  (x, y)
2  3        
3  4  (x, y)
```

This does not look very elegant to me and probably not very efficient. Instead of the loop, I would prefer something like

```
df.loc[df.a % 2 == 0, 'b'] = np.array([mytuple] * sum(df.a % 2 == 0), dtype=tuple)
```

which (of course) does not work. How can I improve my above method by using slicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [57]: df.loc[df.a % 2 == 0, 'b'] = pd.Series([mytuple] * len(df.loc[df.a % 2 == 0])).values

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
   a       b
0  1
1  2  (x, y)
2  3
3  4  (x, y)
```